# How to run shell_exec as same in running the command in command line

Tags: php, python

I have a python script, when i run the script using cmd it works fine. but when i run it using php shell_exec it gives me the error below:

```
scp.SCPException: scp: c7200-ipbasek9-mz.150-1.M10.bin: No such file or directory
```

would just like to know what is the proper way to call the script using shell exec..

Run using cmd

```
E:\Python36>python.exe open.py
```

this successfully run the script

Run using shell_exec

```
$output = shell_exec("E:\Python36\\python.exe E:\Python36\\open.py");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Wild guess: probably issue related to having a different working directory. But this is really just a guess, since you didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Carpetsmoker actually i change the current directory in the php script before i put the shell_exec. i change it to the directory i used in the cmd line. but still giving me the same error. I already have the same current directory which is E:\Python36, both in command line and in shell_exec

Comment: Please post an [mcve].